# How to do a search in rows?

Tags: node.js

I'm just learning not to judge strictly. I try to do Rest Client. And I want to do a data search by rows.
At the moment I just want to try to find the given data in the array. And if one of the lines is the same, the message OK will be displayed, and in the others No. But I have all messages displays No. How to fix it?

```
var data = querystring.stringify({
    Name:    "CEO"
})

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("status: " + res.statusCode);
    var content = ''
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        content += chunk
        for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            if (content[i] === data) {
                console.log('Ок')
            } else {
                console.log('No')
            }
        }
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("error: " + e.message);
});

req.write(data)

req.end()
```

-

```
console.log(`body: ${(chunk)}`):
```

Answer:

```
body: {"rowsCount":75,"rows":[..., {"Id":75,"Name":"CEO"}]}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because your API request is processing a `stream`. What exactly is coming back from that API you are using?

Comment: show us what you are getting back from that api as @ethane has mentioned. For this, do a `console.log()` to print the value of `chunk`.

Comment: @ethane, I added the result, but not the full array, it is big

Comment: @Rai I added the result in response

Answer (score 0):

There are some programming / logical problem with your code that prevent you from getting the desired result.

One of the most important parts (sometimes the trickiest one) of programming is to know the types of data you are dealing with then handle them properly.

As in the problem you are resolving, the data returned from the API is in `JSON` format, and can be treated as `object` in javascript. You don't have to do a string concat to append them to `content` variable. By appending chunk to the `content` variable, you turn the whole set of data return to you to a string, doing a for loop on a string have a very different result compared with on an array.

The second issue is if you look into the data structure that returns to you through the api, the list of records you want to search on is under the `rows` attribute, therefore, you should loop through the `chunk.rows` only.

A suggesting fix for your code will be as follows:

```
var searchQuery = 'SEO';

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= chunk.rows.length; i++) {
            if (chunk.rows[i].Name === searchQuery) {
                console.log('Ок')
            } else {
                console.log('No')
            }
        }
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("error: " + e.message);
});

req.write(data)

req.end()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `for-loop` will skip the first element of the data you get back
2. You aren't accessing the desired search property correctly.
3. Your query is a string for which you are testing equality against an object.

You need to access the `rows` property of your incoming data and then perform your query:

Attempt one:

```
const rowsToSearch = content.rows; // #2
for (var i = 0; i < rowsToSearch.length; i++) {   // #1
    if (rowsToSearch[i].Name === 'CEO') {         // #3
       console.log('Ок')
    } else {
       console.log('No')
    }
}
```

Attempt two, using lodash:

```
const query = { Name: 'CEO' };
const rowsToSearch = chunk.rows; 
for (var i = 0; i < rowsToSearch.length; i++) {   
    if (_.isEqual(rowsToSearch[i], query)) {         
       console.log('Ок')
    } else {
       console.log('No')
    }
}
```

Attempt 3, using ES6 iteration and lodash:

```
const query = { Name: 'CEO' };
const rowsToSearch = chunk.rows;
const result = rowsToSearch.find(row => _.isEqual(row, query));
result ? console.log('OK') : console.log('No');
```

Comment: Be mindful of that `Id` property in your `rows` payload, as it stands this will only try to match `{ Name: 'CEO' }` which means `_.isEqual({ Name: 'CEO' }, { 'Id': 75, Name: 'CEO' })` will be `false`

Comment: I always have this error:        `for (var i = 0; i < rowsToSearch.length; i++) {
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: And apparently the problem is here. `const rowsToSearch = chunk.rows; ` Namely `chunk.rows`

Comment: Then I'd suggest continue appending to the `content` variable and loop over that.